# How to check both conditions met at the same time

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm extremely new to Java, and I'm currently using a Jar allowing the use of some 'Robots learning system'. However, there's one problem I've encountered.

```
while(robot.getX()!=1 && robot.getY()!=5) {
   // blah
}
```

Here, I want the robot to prefer `blah` while both the X isn't 1, and the Y isn't 5 at the same time. When I use it in the provided format, however, it will only do as I instruct while neither his X is 1 or Y is 5, which isn't what I desire.

How can I pull this off? I've tried looking around on the internet, not sure how well I did not knowing the most technical keywords, and in the back of my mind I couldn't think of any double-indented `if` situation where it'd do as I wish. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition becomes `false` as soon as either of its two parts becomes `false`. You need to invert the whole `AND`, like this:

```
while(!(robot.getX()==1 && robot.getY()==5))
    ...
```

or use an `OR`, like this:

```
while(robot.getX()!=1 || robot.getY()!=5)
    ...
```

(both loops use the same logical condition transformed using [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
while (!(X == 1 && Y == 5)) { 
blah
}
```